# how to store a variable and reuse it later within the terminal?

Tags: batch, plink, cisco-router

In a normal cisco switch if I run the following command:

```
copy running-config tftp:
```

the switch will ask me for a IP address.

for my plink I have this:

```
plink -ssh userhere@IP -t copy running-config tftp:
```

Is there a way I can add a fixed IP here instead of me entering it at the command prompt?

Comment: Do you mean storing a variable so that you can use (and reuse) it later within the terminal? What utility are you using to access the switch's terminal? How are you connecting to the switch?

Comment: Yes  i think thats what I want. I am using just a regular batch file, i am sshing to the switch

Comment: What research have you done regarding this so far? Have you reviewed Cisco IOS Script Shell references or guides to see what they say about this? From a quick web search, and with only rudimentary knowledge of the Cisco CLI, I found references online that indicate you should be able to use bash-like syntax for storing and using variables.

Comment: it had nothing to do with cisco. its a batch . thanks tho

Comment: @user3520554: Maybe that's about the "new" IOS XR? I've never used that, but as far as I've had the opportunity to use the traditional Cisco IOS 12.x (assuming the switch runs IOS and not CatOS), it has *no* support for variables that I know of, and no similarities to sh/bash whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

If its a batch file have you tried standard batch variables such as

```
@echo off
set IP_ADDRESS=your.fixed.ip.address

plink -ssh user@%IP_ADDRESS% -t "copy running-config tftp:"
```